# Best Practices to localize entities with EF Code first

Tags: entity-framework, localization, entity-framework-4

I am developing a domain model using EF Code First to persist the data. I have to add support for multilanguage and I would like not to contaminate the domain model with location concepts.

I like that in database exists a ProductTranslate table with title and Language fields but in my domain title belongs to the Product entity.

Someone knows how to get this?

Comment: what is the front end ?

Comment: Hi Yuliam, I don't understand your question, my question is from domain model perspective not from UI perspective

Comment: if the front end is asp.mvc there is a way to infer the localization from property name without adding any attribute, because localization is used in the front end, I think readers need to know..

Answer (score 21):

Here is what I use and works well with code first.

Define a base `Translation` class:

```
using System;

public abstract class Translation<T> where T : Translation<T>, new()
{

  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public string CultureName { get; set; }

  protected Translation()
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
  }

}
```

Define a `TranslationCollection` class:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public class TranslationCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : Translation<T>, new()
{

  public T this[CultureInfo culture]
  {
    get
    {
      var translation = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CultureName == culture.Name);
      if (translation == null)
      {
        translation = new T();
        translation.CultureName = culture.Name;
        Add(translation);
      }

      return translation;
    }
    set
    {
      var translation = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CultureName == culture.Name);
      if (translation != null)
      {
        Remove(translation);
      }

      value.CultureName = culture.Name;
      Add(value);
    }
  }

  public T this[string culture]
  {
    get
    {
      var translation = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CultureName == culture);
      if (translation == null)
      {
        translation = new T();
        translation.CultureName = culture;
        Add(translation);
      }

      return translation;
    }
    set
    {
      var translation = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CultureName == culture);
      if (translation != null)
      {
        Remove(translation);
      }

      value.CultureName = culture;
      Add(value);
    }
  }

  public bool HasCulture(string culture)
  {
    return this.Any(x => x.CultureName == culture);
  }

  public bool HasCulture(CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return this.Any(x => x.CultureName == culture.Name);
  }

}
```

You can then use those classes in your entities, e.g.:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class HelpTopic
{

  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public TranslationCollection<HelpTopicTranslation> Translations { get; set; }

  public string Content
  {
    get { return Translations[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture].Content; }
    set { Translations[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture].Content = value; }
  }

  public HelpTopic()
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    Translations = new TranslationCollection<HelpTopicTranslation>();
  }

}
```

With `HelpTopicTranslation` defined as:

```
using System;

public class HelpTopicTranslation : Translation<HelpTopicTranslation>
{

  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public Guid HelpTopicId { get; set; }

  public string Content { get; set; }

  public HelpTopicTranslation()
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
  }

}
```

Now, for the code first specific side of things, use the following configuration:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using Model;

internal class HelpTopicConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<HelpTopic>
{

  public HelpTopicConfiguration()
  {
    Ignore(x => x.Content); // Ignore HelpTopic.Content since it's a 'computed' field.
    HasMany(x => x.Translations).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.HelpTopicId);
  }

}
```

And add it to your context configurations:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{

  public DbSet<HelpTopic> HelpTopics { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new HelpTopicConfiguration());
  }

}
```

When all of this is done, the following migration is generated:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class AddHelpTopicTable : DbMigration
{

  public override void Up()
  {
    CreateTable(
      "dbo.HelpTopics",
      c => new
      {
        Id = c.Guid(false),
        Name = c.String(),
      })
      .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    CreateTable(
      "dbo.HelpTopicTranslations",
      c => new
      {
        Id = c.Guid(false),
        HelpTopicId = c.Guid(false),
        Content = c.String(),
        CultureName = c.String(),
      })
      .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
      .ForeignKey("dbo.HelpTopics", t => t.HelpTopicId, true)
      .Index(t => t.HelpTopicId);
  }

  public override void Down()
  {
    DropForeignKey("dbo.HelpTopicTranslations", "HelpTopicId", "dbo.HelpTopics");
    DropIndex("dbo.HelpTopicTranslations", new[] { "HelpTopicId" });
    DropTable("dbo.HelpTopicTranslations");
    DropTable("dbo.HelpTopics");
  }

}
```

Any comments and/or improvements are welcome...

Comment: I've made a test app to try this out. Works great. Very elegant solution to a common need. Thank you Julien.

Comment: It looks very good. I haven't tried it, but I think a possible improvement would be to wrap the collection and localizable property in a complex type, like LocalizableString. This way adding new localized properties would be a single line per property.

Comment: this means, all the translation collection will be fetched from DB and filtering for the language code happens on client side right?

Comment: @jayasurya_j Yes, that's correct. I guess it's a limitation :-(

Comment: @jayasura_j not necessarily - depending on how you implement your localization, you can tune your query to filter it within the query. You do not need to fetch all.  This comes at a different cost. If you allow your user to switch languages at will, your rendering can become quite expensive as ALL items will need to be sent.  Since generally speaking you are probably working with a few languages, the extra strings won't be that much of an overhead.