# Clean way for updating object in a collection of abstract objects

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, collections, abstract

As I'm developping an asp net core + ef core 2.0 with localized objects in my model, I adapted the solution provided in the following link to localize my objects [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302393/best-practices-to-localize-entities-with-ef-code-first).

I'm now trying to find a clean way to update my collection of translation when updated object are received in the controller.

For the moment I have a step model class defined this way :

```
public class Step
    {
        //Native properties
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public string ScriptBlock { get; set; }

        //Parent Step Navigation property
        public Nullable<Guid> ParentStepID { get; set; }
        public virtual Step ParentStep { get; set; }

        //Collection of sub steps
        public virtual ICollection<Step> SubSteps { get; set; }

        //MUI Properties
        public TranslationCollection<StepTranslation> Translations { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        //{
        //    get { return Translations[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture].Description; }
        //    set { Translations[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture].Description = value; }
        //}

        public Step()
        {
            //ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            Translations = new TranslationCollection<StepTranslation>();
        }
    }

    public class StepTranslation : Translation<StepTranslation>
    {

        public Guid StepTranslationId { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public StepTranslation()
        {
            StepTranslationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

    }
```

Translation and translationCollection are the same as in the link

```
public class TranslationCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : Translation<T>, new()
{

    public T this[CultureInfo culture]
    {
        // indexer
    }

    public T this[string culture]
    {
        //indexer
    }

    public bool HasCulture(string culture)
    {
        return this.Any(x => x.CultureName == culture);
    }

    public bool HasCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return this.Any(x => x.CultureName == culture.Name);
    }
 }

public abstract class Translation<T> where T : Translation<T>, new()
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string CultureName { get; set; }

    protected Translation()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public bool HasProperty(string name)
    {
        return this.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Any(p => p.Name == name);
    }

}
```

My issue in this sample is how to deal correctly with the PUT method and the Description property of my step controller. When it receive a Step object to update (which is done through a native c# client) only the string Description property of Step might have been created/updated/unchanged. So I have to update/create/do Nothing on the Description of the translation in the correct culture.

My first guess is to add in the TranslationCollection class a method in which I could pass the culture, the name of the property to update or not (Description in this case) and the value of the Description.

But as the TranslationCollection is a collection of abstract objects I don't even if this is a good idea and if it's possible.

If someone would have any advice on it (hoping I was clear enough) it would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally answered my own question, and it was quite simple.

Just had to use the indexer like :
    myobject.Translations[userLang].Name = value;