# Are there are any libraries that support user content localization in aspnetcore?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, localization

The are plenty of resources describing G11n an L10n in aspnetcore including the official docs.

But are there any libraries that simplify the implementation of a **user content** localization? An example could be a content of a blog post that may be translated into multiple languages. Such a library would use a specific table in SQL for storing/retrieving translation.

Here is the possible use case:

```
// this object contains content that user can add manually
public class BlogPost
{
   // should be localised
   public string Content { get; private set; }
}
```

It seems like we can add a collection of "string Content" in order to solve this issue:

```
public class LocalizableContent 
{
    public string CultureInfo { get; private set; }
    public string Content { get; private set; }
}

public class BlogPost
{
    public ICollection<LocalizableContent> Content { get; private set; }
}
```

Note: after making a bit of googling I found a related question (but it gives no answers):
[Best Practices to localize entities with EF Code first | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302393/best-practices-to-localize-entities-with-ef-code-first)

Also, it **doesn't** seem like this library can help:
[github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreLocalization](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreLocalization)

Any suggestions?

Comment: in cloudscribe we do that with multi-tenancy, so each tenant can have a different language, case study here https://www.cloudscribe.com/blog/2017/03/28/case-study-historic-place-names-of-wales

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement your content localization library without the need to use third parties. Personaly I do something like below:

```
public class BlogPost {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public ICollection<BloPostLocalized> Localizations { get; set; }
}
```

Create a localized class for BlogPost:

```
public class BlogPostLocalized {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public BlogPostId { get; set; }
 public BlogPost { get; set; }
 public string Culture { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that the main BloPost has no Title nor Content fields, because we will have them defined in the `BlogPostLocalized` class for neutral and localized cultures.

So each blog post will have multiple localized versions that can be fetched simply from the db as a child of the main post.