# Is there an OCP-friendly way to dynamically choose which collection in a DbContext to access?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, open-closed-principle

I'm working on a method to retrieve a collection of records from a database. The records are stored in separate tables based on an aspect of the data they contain. Suppose it looks like this.

```
public class EnglishPhrase : IPhrase
{
    public string Text {get; set;}
}

public class SpanishPhrase: IPhrase 
{ 
    public string Text {get; set;} 
}

// This is actually a DbContext with DbSets. 
// I have not implemented DbContext in this example to
// alleviate overhead when reproducing the situation.
public class MyContext
{
    public EnglishPhrase[] EnglishPhrases { get; set; }
    public SpanishPhrase[] SpanishPhrases { get; set; }
}
```

My method needs to pick either English or Spanish phrases based on a language argument. Right now I'm accomplishing it with a `switch` statement.

```
public IEnumerable<IPhrase> GetPhrases(string language)
{
    IEnumerable<IPhrase> result = null;

    MyContext context = new MyContext();

    switch(language)
    {
        case "English":
            result = context.EnglishPhrases.ToList();
            break;
        case "Spanish":
            result = context.SpanishPhrases.ToList();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I used the `switch` because I'm going to be adding more languages later on, but that means *I'll have to modify this method* every time I do that. However, I can't help but feel like there could be a better way to do this.

Could I do something else, such as adding a `Language` property to the `IPhrase` interface, that would allow my method to access the right `DbSet` that way, or is the `switch` the tersest way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Do you need to add a database table if you add a new language as well? If so, I wouldn't recommend it. In general, adding a language in a multilangage environment should never lead to re-code anything.

Comment: Can you modify it to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302393/best-practices-to-localize-entities-with-ef-code-first

Comment: @Stefan That's correct. For example, to add French support, I would add a `FrenchPhrase` class, a `FrenchPhrases` property to my context, and (currently) a `case "French"` block to my method.

Comment: @JAF; ok so, then your *closed for change* concerns are much broader then the `switch` statement. I would reconsider your approach, and use 1 table. If is going to be huge, use a more dynamic approach. ... btw, if it's just multi-language support in an application, you can also use `Resource` (resx) files.

Comment: @Stefan: Like one collection of a new `Phrase` class, containing `Text` and `Language` properties. The existing tables in the database can be kept separate by creating a view containing all translations, and mapping the `DbContext` to that. Thanks!
Also, there actually are `resx` files for UI translations. This method and stuff is on the backend for report generation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what comes to my mind. Treat it more like pseudo code. You need to fit it to your scenerio. But the main concept of Open-Closed Principle is included. I used Generic class to build language object.

If you want add more languages just create new class. You can create some kind of Language class and then English class (and other languages) can inherit from it.

You can use Dependency Injection and just manipulate with interfaces.

```
public interface IPhrase<T>
{
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Phrase<T> : IPhrase<T> where T : Language
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public Phrase(string text, DbContext context)
    {
        Text = text;
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
}

public class Language
{
    //do smth
}
public class English : Language
{
    //do smth
}

public class Spanish : Language
{
    //do smth
}
```

Usage:

```
DbContext _context = new DbContext();
Phrase<English> en = new Phrase<English>("Your english text goes here", _context);

public IEnumerable<IPhrase<T>> GetPhrases(Phrase<T> language)
{
    return language.DbSet.ToList();
}
```

GetPhrases method can be even placed in Phrase class.

I hope it helps you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could include within the IPhrase model a “language” property. And then when you load the context:
Result = context.Where( p => p.Language == languageParam).ToList()

Not sure if this would be easier for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use TPH to simplify you context and action.

Models:

```
public enum PhraseType
{
    English,
    Spanish
}

public abstract class Phrase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public PhraseType PhraseType { get; set; }
}

public class EnglishPhrase : Phrase {}

public class SpanishPhrase : Phrase {}
```

DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Phrase> Phrases { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Phrase>()
        .HasDiscriminator(p => p.PhraseType)
        .HasValue<EnglishPhrase>(PhraseType.English)
        .HasValue<SpanishPhrase>(PhraseType.Spanish);
}
```

Action method:

```
public IEnumerable<Phrase> GetPhrases(string language)
{
    // assuming the language parameter is "english" or "spanish"
    var theType = $"YourNamespace.{language}Phrase";

    //assuming your models are in the current assembly
    Type type = TypeInfo.GetType(theType, true, true);

    MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("OfType").MakeGenericMethod(type);

    var obj = appContext.Phrases.AsQueryable();

    var result = method.Invoke(obj, new[] { obj });
    return result as IEnumerable<Phrase>;
}
```

A little explanation:

You Use TPH (Table per Hierarchy) so you only need to create one `DbSet`.

When you want to return all `EnglishPhrase`s you can use `context.Phrases.OfType<EnglishPhrase>()` but since your parameter determines the type, you need to use reflection to call the correct `OfType` method.

You can put all those reflections codes into a helper class so your action will be cleaner.

In future when you want to add more languages you just have to edit the `PhraseType` enum and add extra `HasValue` in your Fluent API. No changes are needed in the Action method.

I just tested this on my system and it worked.